# Silverlight - Caching On REST-based Services

Tags: silverlight, webrequest

I have a Silverlight application that is interacting with a WCF service. This service uses a RESt-based format. In my application, I am hitting this service with a WebRequest object. I'm making my call as follows:

```
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(serviceUrl);
request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(Operation_Completed), request);
```

I've noticed that subsequent calls are being called. This is NOT what I want. I do not want anything cached. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [CachePolicy.Level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.cachepolicy.aspx) property. It gives you fine-grained control over caching behavior.